# How to pass a List from an abstract Class to another class?

Tags: java

*Employee* is my abstract class and it has *FixedPosition* as a daughter class. Company has a method called addEmployee() that must receive a type Employee and then add the List from Employee to its own List.

```
Company company = new Company("Hi");
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Later I fill up my List but I don't know how to send a type Employee into the method from Company.

```
employees.add(new FixedPosition(name, occupation, salary, monthsContract));
company.addEmployee();
```

Comment: Change the parameter list of `addEmployee()` to add a new parameter `Employee toAdd`. What is the problem you have with that?

Comment: In the Company class the method I have goes like this:                                        public void addEmployee(Employee newEmployee) {} but when I try to use the method on main it gives me an error since employees is a list

Comment: You can add the employees with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `addEmployee()` has no argument. Rewrite it so that it gets an employee object solves your problem.

```java
public void addEmployee( Employee e ) {
    this.employees.add(e);
}
```

Your company class should have the list of employees.

Comment: Thanks but if I try to use the method addEmployee to send the employees I can't because it is a List.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to overload method `addEmployee` in your `Company` class to support handling of an employee list:

```
public void addEmployee(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees.addAll(employees);
}
```

Or you can call existing `Company` method with a single employee in a loop:

```
employees.forEach(company::addEmployee);
```